# Cron job runs 2 times and then stops

Tags: php, mysql, cron, cpanel

I m trying to configure a cron job via cpanel. What i want to do is execute a php script that updates a value in a mysql database table every minute. i tryed 2 cron commands :

```
wget -O – -q "URL_HERE"
```

and

```
usr/local/bin/php -q /home/user/public_html/filename.php
```

note that its a very small script with tiny execution time, so it should be ok.
for testing purposes I configured it to run every minute to see if it works.
Here is the problem:
the cron job runs ok for the first two times , but then it stops. for example if the time is 12:00, the script will run on 12:01, then on 12:02, but **NOT** on 12:03 .. 12:04 and so on. What could be the problem here? 
thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your full crontab entry

Comment: add a crontab entry in similar way 
* * * * * /var/www/html/magento/cron.sh

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your crontab entry is correct...

For running a cron every minute, one needs to add entry something like

```
* * * * * "username" "task to execute"
```